# Soft high pitched sound

Tags: guitar, recording

Hi all i'm fresh here and this is my first post on this website.
My name is mirko and i hope this is the right place to post this

i have this problem here and i was hopiung to get an answer so if it happens again i can fix it with your help , i will put the viedeo right here so you can listen :

The hiss goes away when I touch the metal part of my cable but the problem it's not permanent I mean for a period of time I have not this hiss and some time after it comes back

Comment: are these "solderless" cables? I did a quick check and the first hit for a non-kit version of a planet waves switchable cable was solderless. Bad connections might be a source of signal ingress.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds to me like a grounding problem in one of your pieces of equipment but the sound is unusually high pitched for this. It can sometimes come naturally in a guitar when not touching the strings or any metal part, the hiss should disappear when touching almost any metal part of your guitar or amp. Does this only happen when recording? If not:

- Does the hissing stop when touching any metal part of the guitar?
- Does the hissing stop when touching any metal part of the amp?
- Does the hissing stop when touching any metal part of the lead?
- The piece of equipment where the hissing doesn't stop touching most of its metal parts may need to be seen by a technician to be fixed.
- Check your guitar for bad grounding, either a ground loop or loose wire.
- Check your amp for dodgy grounding, either a ground loop or loose wire.

If this is not the problem, it could be a problem of outer emf. This would explain why it only happens at certain times. Is there an electrical thing always turned on when this hissing happens? (Usually high voltage) Try turning all electrical things in your house off (except guitar and amp) including lights and see if the hissing stops. If you are in an apartment, try take your equipment to another persons house and see if the hissing stops. Try to open up the back panel on your guitar, do you see some kind of paint that is around the wood in the electrical section? The paint that may be there is called shielding paint. If this paint isn't there you may have to get a technician to add shielding paint to the insides of your guitar (you could try do this yourself if you want, google shielding paint for guitar).

As a last resort, try to swap around equipment to find the problem. Use a different lead, use a different amp, use a different guitar. If these don't offer a solution, I'm hoping someone with more experience in electronics may know the answer. I know most of this knowledge by the internet, not large amounts of experience so I can't be certain. Try asking on electricalengineering.stackexchange.

Hope this helps. Good Luck. :)

Comment: I forgot to mention (maybe) that the hiss doesent exist when I don't plug any cable in my amp. And when I plug a cable and bring it close to the the back of the amp where the power supply is and the speaker cable or another metal part it stops and become quiet

Answer (score -1):

Make sure your cables are "balanced" (meaning they have a ground). Any jacks should have two components for mono and three for stereo. They'll be divided by a strip of rubber on the jack.

Also make sure you're running into balanced TRS or XLR ports in addition to using balanced cables.

Comment: This is reasonable advice for vocal & keyboard signal chains, but it will not help electric guitarists, who exclusively use unbalanced cables – the equipment simply does not have TRS or XLR ports, except for DI units designed for plugging into a mixer.